# Issue with the java classpath in shell script - jars not detectable

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, java-8

I am trying to run my java source code using a jar file which I have created in Ubuntu and I am facing an issue of my jar files not being detected. I have copied all my jar files in a subfolder and placed my sourcecode jar outside. I am trying to call main function from my main jar and I am able to do it successfully but somehow relative jars that are inside my relative subfolders are not detectable. I tried everything including creating or testing a manifest file but it did not work out. My code is running fine in eclipse IDE. Below is my shell script code -

```
LIB=./ChainLib/
echo "$LIB"
echo ls "$LIB"
CLASSPATH=./ChainLib/*.jar
export CLASSPATH=./ChainLib/*.jar
echo Classpath_is "$CLASSPATH"
#$(JARS=("$LIB"/*.jar); IFS=:; 
#echo "${JARS[*]}")
jarnames=`ls ./ChainLib/*.jar`
for eachfile in $jarnames
do
echo $eachfile
done
#java -cp TestBlockchainkaranl.jar Testing
xvfb-run -a java -jar TestBlock.jar
```

When I run above script I get below:

```
bash RunBlockchain.sh
./ChainLib/
ls ./ChainLib/
Classpath_is ./ChainLib/*.jar
./ChainLib/bcpkix-jdk14-1.57.jar
./ChainLib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.59.jar
./ChainLib/commons-codec-1.11.jar
./ChainLib/commons-compress-1.5.jar
./ChainLib/fabric-sdk-java-1.2.1.jar
./ChainLib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar
./ChainLib/httpclient-4.5.6.jar
./ChainLib/httpcore-4.4.10.jar
./ChainLib/javax.json-1.1.jar
./ChainLib/netty-common-5.0.0.Alpha2.jar
./ChainLib/org-apache-commons-logging.jar
u1 Username
Y Filestatus
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hyperledger/fabric/sdk/User
        at Testing.main(Testing.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.User
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

How can I make sure this issue doesn't occur and my jars get detected successfully?

Update: I am adding the manifest file which I had created and zipped it in the jar file

Here is the manifest code:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Testing
  Class-Path:/home/ubuntu/KaranHyperledger/java/Blockchaintool/ChainLib/*.jar
  Class-Path:/home/ubuntu/KaranHyperledger/java/Blockchaintool/TestBlock.jar
```

Comment: Try to remove whitespaces from start of your `Class-Path` entry. Also you do not need to list jar which you running.

Comment: Also try to expand `*`. And list it in one entry comma separated.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't check `CLASSPATH` environment variable. You have to pass it explicitly.

```
java -cp TestBlockchainkaranl.jar:$CLASSPATH Testing
```

Comment: how can I do it with xvfb-run -a java -jar TestBlock.jar? is the correct statement xvfb-run -a java -jar TestBlock.jar :$CLASSPATH Testing ?

Comment: @Kdevel you can't specify custom classpath in command line in case you use `-jar` argument. It should be in manifest.

Comment: I created a manifest file with syntax Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Testing
  Class-Path:/home/ubuntu/KaranHyperledger/java/Blockchaintool/ChainLib/*.jar
  Class-Path:/home/ubuntu/KaranHyperledger/java/Blockchaintool/TestBlock.jar but it is not detecting main manifest attribute somehow and giving error main manifest attribute not found

Comment: @Kdevel can you edit your question and add your manifest to it?

Comment: Or better create another question because it is completely different issue.